# How to move a Textview dynamically on the screen? (framelayout)

Tags: android, textview

I have a app that shows the camera view on the screen on a FrameLayout. The screen is in fixed LandScape mode.

I need to write a textView with dynamically determined coordinates of the screen. The coordinates are determined in percentages, for example :

write the textview on the coorinates x=80% of the screen & y=20% of the screen. write the textview on the coorinates x=35% of the screen & y=55% of the screen.

how to do it? i already have the percentages, i only need to know how to use them to write the textview on the desired position of the frameLayout

code examples are welcome

i tried with this but doesn't works, the textview isn't moved:

```
TextView poi..... etc etc
poi.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams((int)(w*(xCoordPercent/100)), h/2));
```

thanks

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is animating a TextView. If it is the case, you should have a look at tutorials about it, it's fairly straightforward for basic movements like that and it could give you ideas while you await for more answers here.

Comment: no no, i dont want to animate it, i only want to move the textivew on the screen, from left to right, from up to down, dependent of dinamically generated coordinates. Later i will use a image, but now i need to mote a textview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MarginLayoutParams params=(MarginLayoutParams )poi.getLayoutParams();
params.leftMargin=80;
//here 100 means 100px,not 80% of the width of the parent view
//you may need a calculation to convert the percentage to pixels. 
params.topMargin=50;
poi.setLayoutParams(params);
```

This may help.

Comment: it doesn't works. POI is still painted in the top left corner of the screen. I have to repaint the window or something? the FrameLayout haves a cameraview on it also. What is wrong? im stuck