# android sdk set imageview x y coordinates

Tags: java, android

I'm using an absolutelayout (I know its deprecated). I am adding imageview dynamically but I can't change its position from the top left corner of the screen.

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.orb1);
this.addContentView(iv, new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(80, 80, 200, 200));
```

However, this creates the image with top left at 0, 0 instead of anywhere else. If I change the last two values of Layout Params it still remains in that position.

Can someone assist? Thanks.

Edit: Using relative layout still doesn't work

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.orb1);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(80, 80);
params.topMargin=50;
params.leftMargin=50;
this.addContentView(iv, params);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add view to a layout using addView method, because layout params can be applied to a layout not window, so do the following:

```
RelativeLayout rlMain = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.orb1);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(80, 80);
params.topMargin=50;
params.leftMargin=50;
rlMain.addView(iv, params);
```

replace mainLayout to the id which you are providing to relativelayout, imageVIew being supposed to add.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't archieve this by using a AbsoluteLayout. You should use a RelativeLayout or FrameLayout to control the position of your views precisely.

I once answered a similar question. Please see here: [How to move a Textview dynamically on the screen? (framelayout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594143/how-to-move-a-textview-dynamically-on-the-screen-framelayout/7594344#7594344)

Comment: I mean,this imageview itself should be within a relativelayout.

Comment: I changed the layout to realtivelayout (the xml file).